# How do I get the current date in ISO8601 format in db2

Tags: sql, database, db2

I would like to get the current date in ISO8601 format in sql db2

I need help

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you mean the ISO 8601 format `YYYY-MM-DD`?

Comment: What does `current_date` return?

Comment: Try the `TO_CHAR (CURRENT DATE, ...)` scalar function described in the Db2 documentation.

Comment: E.g. `CHAR(current_date, ISO)`.

Comment: I am trying to get the current date under the following format : "YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000Z"

Answer (score 0):

Under most circumstances, you would just use the current date.  In DB2, you can use one or:

```
select current date
select current_date
```

(I prefer the version with the underscore because it is compatible with other databases.)

If you want to ensure the format, then you don't want a *date*, you want a string, so convert it to a string:

```
select to_char(current_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```